# The layout changes greatly on rotation. How to fix it?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, orientation

I made a layout for my app using linear layout. It looks fine and works fine but on rotation the layout changes very differently like the edit text becomes very small and disappears when keyboard appears. So how to provide a consistent look for my application. Or what am I missing?

Here is the code of the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.nobodyme.errorrepository.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Folders"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/foldername"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/enterFolderButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="OK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5">

        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/folderlistview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Create folders to add error"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here how it looks on my device, four images below show how it looks on vertical and horizontal position with and without clicking on edit text, i.e with keyboard on and off.

[image: vertical - without keyboard]

[image: vertical - with keyboard]

[image: horizontal - without keyboard]

[image: horizontal - with keyboard]

Comment: That's what I would expect given your layout.  You have a full width list view, and full width is now very large. How exactly to fix it depends on what you want it to look like in landscape, we can't give you an exact answer.  You can however make a separate landscape layout with views with the same ids and it should just work to load the new layout

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate? Full width list view is a problem? Don't all the apps have full width list view, like whatsapp , gmail? Or does all apps do the same thing like you suggest?

Comment: Its not a problem, but think about it-  what else do you expect it to look like in landscape?  Yes, providing separate landscape layouts is common.